# How to build the Maven project package wise?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I have 5 packages

```
com/test1
com/test2
com/test3
com/test4
com/test4
```

I want to build the war only any of one or tow packages at a time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: You are talking about a war ? Why would you like to build package wise? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: in one project i have all the codes i don't wont to build all codes it increases the war size. even some package code not useful. for example i have 3 users i want to send each package build to each user. and i don't wont to create separate project for each user, sometimes 4th user will need all 3 package build

Comment: If the code does not belong there remove from there...Are this real code changes what you are sending to different users? This what you are doing will not working correctly if you like to make a release from it...What do you mean by `all the codes` ? Do you mean the source code of your app?

Comment: Yes its my source code(all packages)

Answer (score 1):

Try this for jars:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>your_package_folder_here/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And this for wars:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/your_package_folder_here/**</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Don't forget to use `/**` at the end of the full path of the package folder you want to exclude `/**` is for folders `/*` is for files. your jar file will be placed in target without the package. Rule applies for both cases.

---

If you want to exclude multiple packages then my first advice is to read the plugin api first:

> packagingExcludes
>   java.lang.String 2.1-alpha-2
>   false true The
>   comma separated list of tokens to exclude from the WAR before
>   packaging. This option may be used to implement the skinny WAR use
>   case. Note that you can use the Java Regular Expressions engine to
>   include and exclude specific pattern using the expression %regex[].
>   Hint: read the about (?!Pattern).

Then finally you could get to this example:

```
(...)
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/com/steelzack/b2b2bwebapp/excludefolder/**,WEB-INF/classes/com/steelzack/b2b2bwebapp/excludefolder2/**</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
(...)
```

Comment: what happened? carefull with the exclude node. they should be your folder like: `com/package/something/**`. Also in the target you will see that package in the classes folder, but not in the jar. if you check the contents then your package should not be there. Example:  `<exclude>com/mypackage/something/**</exclude>`

Comment: I've tried it again here in a sample project, and it does work!. I've used this quite a few times already and it has always worked for me.

Comment: @PrasadVS you can also try in different phases. in maven you have clean, build, test, also package which is the one im using for the example. just choose the best that suits your needs.

Comment: i'm generating war not jar <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-jar</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>war</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>com/test/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

Comment: Basic element 'warSourceExcludes' must not contain child elements. this is the error i'm getting

Comment: @PrasadVS I've just added a solution for war files. It works locally for me. I've just tested it for another sample project

Comment: It's working fine joao-esperancinha, and i want to exclude some dependency also.

Comment: how can i exclude multiple packages?

Comment: have you tried with multiple exclude nodes? I didnt try that but maybe that would help.

Comment: @PrasadVS I've given you now an example of everything you've mentioned so far and I have updated the response. You need to separate all the packages you want to exclude with a coma.

Comment: @PrasadVS Did you ran into more problems with the setup I've suggested?